# Performing regex on a stream

Tags: java, regex

I have some large text files which im going to preform consecutive matching on (just capturing, not replacing). Im thinking its not such a good idea to keep the whole file in memory, but rather use a `Reader`.

What i know about the input is that if there's a match, its not going to span more than 5 lines. So my idea was to have some sort of buffer which just keeps these 5 lines, or so, do the first search, and continue. But it has to "know" where the regex match ended for this to work. e.g if the match ends at line 2 it should start the next search from here. Is it possible to do something like this in an **efficient** way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use a `Scanner` and the [`findWithinHorizon`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("thefile"));
String nextMatch = s.findWithinHorizon(yourPattern, 0);
```

From the api on [`findWithinHorizon`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> If horizon is 0, then the horizon is ignored and this method continues to search through the input looking for the specified pattern without bound. In this case it may buffer all of the input searching for the pattern.

A side note: When matching on multiple lines, you might want to look at the constants `Pattern.MULTILINE` and `Pattern.DOTALL`.

Comment: +1; and read the API to understand how `Scanner` handles `IOException`.

Answer (score 3):

[Streamflyer](https://github.com/rwitzel/streamflyer) is able to apply regular expressions on character streams.

Note that I'm the author of it.

Comment: Too bad your libary is not maintained anymore. :-( Any good alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

The java implementation of regular expression engine looks unsuitable for streaming processing.

I would rather advocate another approach rooted on "derivative combinators".

The researcher Matt Might has published relevant posts about "derivative combinators" on his blog and suggests a Scala implementation here:

- http://matt.might.net/articles/parsing-with-derivatives/
- http://matt.might.net/articles/nonblocking-lexing-toolkit-based-on-regex-derivatives/

On my side, I succeed to improve this implementation by adding some "capture" ability, but I feel it could have a significant impact on memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;  //BufferedReader //FileReader //FileWriter //PrintWriter
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class ScannerReader { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {  
            ReadDataFromFileTestRegex("[A-Za-z_0-9-%$!]+@[A-Za-z_0-9-%!$]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",
                                      "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\TextFiles\\Emails.txt",
                                      "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\TextFiles\\\\output.txt");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File is not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public static void ReadDataFromFileTestRegex (String theReg, String FileToRead, String FileToWrite) throws Exception {

        PrintWriter Pout = new PrintWriter(FileToWrite);            
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(theReg); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(FileToRead)); 
        String line = br.readLine();       
        while (line != null) {          
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            while (m.find()) {
                if (m.group().length() != 0) {
                    System.out.println( m.group().trim());
                }             
                System.out.println("Start index: " + m.start());
                System.out.println("End index  : " + m.end());
                Pout.println(m.group());  //print the result to the output file
            }
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        Pout.flush();   
        br.close();
        Pout.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please enhance your promising post by adding a sample code usage and a sample output?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Scanner.matchAll()` is what you looking for. It simplified my code.

```java
try(var scanner = new Scanner(Path.of(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
    var result = scanner.findAll(PATTERN)
                .map(MatchResult::group)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Answer (score -5):

With Java8 you can do this pretty simply and possibly in parallel-

```
// Create a pattern-matcher
private static final Pattern emailRegex = Pattern.compile("([^,]+?)@([^,]+)");

//Read content of a file
String fileContent = Files.lines(Path.get("/home/testFile.txt")
                              .collect(Collector.join(" "));
// Apply the pattern-matcher
List<String> results = matcherStream(emailRegex.matcher(fileContent))
                           .map(b -> b[2])
                           .collect(Collector.toList()));
```

Another way can be -

```
List<String> results = Files.lines(Path.get("/home/testFile.txt")
                              .parallelStream()
                              .forEach(s -> "use regex")
                              .collect(Collector.toList());
```

Comment: you took this content from another answer without referencing it (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24663422/1902625) and it wasn't even done completely.  `matcherStream` method is not defined.