# Collect HashSet / Java 8 / Regex Pattern / Stream API

Tags: java, regex, collections, java-8, java-stream

Recently I change version of the JDK 8 instead 7 of my project and now I overwrite some code snippets using new features that came with Java 8.

```
final Matcher mtr = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);

HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>() {{
    while (mtr.find()) add(mtr.group().toLowerCase());
}};
```

**How I can write this code using Stream API ?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A `Matcher`-based spliterator implementation can be quite simple if you reuse the JDK-provided `Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator`:

```
public class MatcherSpliterator extends AbstractSpliterator<String[]>
{
  private final Matcher m;

  public MatcherSpliterator(Matcher m) {
    super(Long.MAX_VALUE, ORDERED | NONNULL | IMMUTABLE);
    this.m = m;
  }

  @Override public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String[]> action) {
    if (!m.find()) return false;
    final String[] groups = new String[m.groupCount()+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) groups[i] = m.group(i);
    action.accept(groups);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Note that the spliterator provides *all* matcher groups, not just the full match. Also note that this spliterator supports parallelism because `AbstractSpliterator` implements a splitting policy.

Typically you will use a convenience stream factory:

```
public static Stream<String[]> matcherStream(Matcher m) {
  return StreamSupport.stream(new MatcherSpliterator(m), false);
}
```

This gives you a powerful basis to concisely write all kinds of complex regex-oriented logic, for example:

```
private static final Pattern emailRegex = Pattern.compile("([^,]+?)@([^,]+)");
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String emails = "kid@gmail.com, stray@yahoo.com, miks@tijuana.com";
  System.out.println("User has e-mail accounts on these domains: " +
      matcherStream(emailRegex.matcher(emails))
      .map(gs->gs[2])
      .collect(joining(", ")));
}
```

Which prints

```
User has e-mail accounts on these domains: gmail.com, yahoo.com, tijuana.com
```

For completeness, your code will be rewritten as

```
Set<String> set = matcherStream(mtr).map(gs->gs[0].toLowerCase()).collect(toSet());
```

Comment: Nicely done! It would be good if something like this were migrated into the `Matcher` API itself.

Comment: Note: an API `Matcher.results()` returning `Stream<MatchResult>` has been integrated into JDK 9: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071479

Comment: @StuartMarks +1 and I'm especially looking forward to `replaceAll(Function)`, which is a substitute for possibly the ugliest boilerplate idiom left over from early versions: `StringBuffer b = ...; while (m.find()) { ... m.appendReplacement(b, ...); } m.appendTail(b);`

Answer (score 9):

[Marko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663422/1441122) demonstrates how to get matches into a stream using a `Spliterator`. Well done, give that man a big +1! Seriously, make sure you upvote his answer before you even consider upvoting this one, since this one is entirely derivative of his.

I have only a small bit to add to Marko's answer, which is that instead of representing the matches as an array of strings (with each array element representing a match group), the matches are better represented as a `MatchResult` which is a type invented for this purpose. Thus the result would be a `Stream<MatchResult>` instead of `Stream<String[]>`. The code gets a little simpler, too. The `tryAdvance` code would be

```
    if (m.find()) {
        action.accept(m.toMatchResult());
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

The `map` call in his email-matching example would change to

```
    .map(mr -> mr.group(2))
```

and the OP's example would be rewritten as

```
Set<String> set = matcherStream(mtr)
                      .map(mr -> mr.group(0).toLowerCase())
                      .collect(toSet());
```

Using `MatchResult` gives a bit more flexibility in that it also provides offsets of match groups within the string, which could be useful for certain applications.

Comment: +1 and thanks for the praise :) I never took note of the `MatchResult` part of `Matcher` API, it's definitely the way to go.

Comment: Note: an API `Matcher.results()` returning `Stream<MatchResult>` has been integrated into JDK 9: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071479

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can turn this into a `Stream` without writing your own [Spliterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html), but, I don't know why you would want to.

`Matcher.find()` is a state changing operation on the `Matcher` object so running each find() in a parallel stream would produce inconsistent results.  Running the stream in serial wouldn't have better performance that the Java 7 equivalent and would be harder to understand.

Comment: I don't want write loop for it, and it will better to write inline. Regarding performance in this case `Matcher` will be have small count of the groups.

Comment: If you wan't onliner why dont you create a method for it. And then use it like this

     `Set<String> groups = MatcherUtil.groupsOfPattern(pattern,input);`

Comment: I would argue that a Matcher-based Stream would be a very welcome feature. For example, Clojure offers `re-seq` as the primary primitive to use for regex processing.

Answer (score 3):

What about [`Pattern.splitAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) ?

```
Stream<String> stream = Pattern.compile(regex).splitAsStream(input);
```

and then a collector to get a set.

```
Set<String> set = stream.map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Useful in some cases, but doesn't match the OP's question. The OP has a pattern that matches stuff he wants to put into the set. `splitAsStream` matches delimiters, stuff **between** the values that end up in the stream and eventually into the destination set.

Comment: You are right, but the OP may adapt its code. Anyway it is interesting to be aware of this alternative, especially because the others "java 8 style" answers propose a much more uglier code that the java 7 one.

Comment: Remember that beauty is in the eye of the beholder. Many will agree there are few idioms in Java uglier than creating an anonymous HashSet subclass just to save a line of code. Also, proposing an API extension should not be equalled with proposing ugly client code. Finally, twisting a regex solution from positive to negative match just to avoid writing such an extension can easily result in code which is not just ugly, but incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
public class MakeItSimple {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\TextFiles\\Emails.txt"));

    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();          
    while ( s.hasNext()) {
       String r = s.next();
       if (r.matches("([^,]+?)@([^,]+)")) {
          set.add(r);
       }
    }   
    set.stream().map( x -> x.toUpperCase()).forEach(x -> print(x)); 
    s.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation using Spliterator interface.

```
    // To get the required set
   Set<String> result = (StreamSupport.stream(new MatcherGroupIterator(pattern,input ),false))
           .map( s -> s.toLowerCase() )
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    ...
    private static class MatcherGroupIterator implements Spliterator<String> {
      private final Matcher matcher;

      public MatcherGroupIterator(Pattern p, String s) {
        matcher = p.matcher(s);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String> action) {
        if (!matcher.find()){
            return false;
        }
        action.accept(matcher.group());
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public Spliterator<String> trySplit() {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public long estimateSize() {
        return Long.MAX_VALUE;
      }

      @Override
      public int characteristics() {
        return Spliterator.NONNULL;
      }
  }
```

Comment: I think this code example shows why it's not worth converting your Java 7 code into a Java 8 Stream.  Even if you say "well, I'll only have to write this Spliterator once", your actual stream code is just as verbose as your Java 7 version PLUS you now have an additional class to maintain

Comment: This could have been quite a bit shorter---*and* supported parallelism---if it was based on `AbstractSpliterator`. Another thing: each match should not be just a string, but a list of all available matcher *groups*.

Comment: @dkatzel If one's only use case is as simple as OP's, then writing a whole Splitetor for it isn't much of a benefit. However, having the regex match results available in the form of a Stream supports a much wider range of much more complex use cases.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't think parallelism can be supported since the Match state is mutable and is updated each time `find()` is called.  The javadoc for Matcher explicitly states that the "instances are NOT threadsafe for use by multiple concurrent threads"

Comment: @dkatzel `spliterators are not expected to be thread-safe; instead, implementations of parallel algorithms using spliterators should ensure that the spliterator is only used by one thread at a time.` (from Spliterator javadoc)