# Applying Regex over a Stream to extract a string

Tags: java, regex, http, stream

We are using a REST API call that returns a string of a very large size. We are performing

```
httpget.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

to get the string returned by the REST call. Then we apply regex over this string to extract the substring that we require. When the string returned by the REST call is huge, we are facing Out Of Memory issues with the JVM.

We can also get the data from the REST call as a stream using

```
httpget.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

But is it possible to apply regex over the stream and extract the string that we require?

Comment: how big is the string? I don't expect `OutOfMemory` occurs even for 1mb string data

Comment: @ Reddy : Yet, it does for us.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/fge/largetext), it may help you; requires that you write the input to a file first (the bytes, of course, not the characters) and then use your regex on the file. Still, if you have OOMs, it means you have a lot of concurrent requests.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, who's writing the regex, and do they know what they're doing?  You should make sure the regex is as efficient as possible, because you've probably got very little wiggle room.

Answer (score 2):

These previous answers show a few options:

1. [Performing regex on a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013669/performing-regex-on-a-stream)
2. [Applying a regular expression to a Java I/O Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716927/applying-a-regular-expression-to-a-java-i-o-stream)

I think that [Scanner.findWithinHorizon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) mentioned by the first answer (above) may be an interesting option.

Comment: Just what I was thinking!  I'm not in a position to test this, but you should be able to create the Scanner directly from the stream returned that's by `getResponseBodyAsStream()`.  You can specify the encoding, too.